# CSS white-space within element having no set width

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a span within another span where the child has no set width so the text is going onto a new line after just 1 or 2 words.

Here's the code and a jsfiddle which will help to better see what I mean.

```
<span class="container">Lorem ipsum dolor
    <span class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut risus enim, tincidunt ac tristique quis, vulputate sed nulla. Nam imperdiet imperdiet mollis. Vestibulum sed elit lorem, et luctus massa. Vivamus eleifend ante vel odio lacinia.
    </span>
</span>
```

css:

```
.container {
    width:auto;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}

.child {
    position:absolute;
    top:35px;
    left:10px;
    max-width:500px;
    background-color:yellow;
    /*white-space:nowrap; This does not work because the text does not wrap after 500px */ 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RRx6r/

What I ideally want to achieve is the child span expanding to a maximum of 500px depending on the quantity of text in it.

white-space:nowrap does not work because the line never breaks.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
display:block;
```

to either the `.container`, or to both the `.container` and the `.child` (depending on issues with your other css rules). Note that you need to set a max-width on the container as well, else it will grow to whatever space is available.

[See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VubBJ/)

Comment: OK. So if I don't (can't) have the container set to display:block, then the only other way around it is to set a width on the child element? Is that right?

Comment: If the container can't be a block, you can try setting it as a 'table-cell': http://jsfiddle.net/R5bE8/ but that could produce unwanted results in the layout an probably requires a 'clearfix' somewhere.

Comment: Think I'll stick to setting a fixed width on the child. There's not going to be many occurrences where the amount of text will cause it to be much less than 500px wide. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you position an element absolutely (`position:absolute;`), than you have to set a specific width. Otherwise the element (and for sure an inline element like `SPAN`) will shrink to the minimum width required.

One option could be to set the parent element to `display: block;`, which causes that it expands to the maximum width available. That way the inner element has a chance to expand to 500px width.

http://jsfiddle.net/RRx6r/2/

Answer (score 0):

In short: Change the parent span to a DIV

That happened to you because the parent Span is setting the maximum width in which the child span is showing on.

If you want the child span to be longer, you can:

Change the span to a div, which is the same as the span, but it takes the full width of its parent container by default, it would be the equivalent of putting `display:block` into your CSS, DIV and SPAN are empty elements with just that property really, display:block, or display:inline.